# Save information using windows 8 Isolated Storage

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, isolatedstorage

I'm developing a Windows metro (Store) app and i need to store a List.
I'm using [this dll (Windows 8 Isolated Storage)](https://isolatedstoragew8.codeplex.com/) but I'm getting a error.

```
public void saveInformation()
{     
    var storage = new Setting<List<JobProposal>>();
    storage.SaveASync("data", this.JobsList); 
}
```

And I'm getting:

> The type or namespace name 'Setting' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I've added the dll as a reference. Do I need to be "using" something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using IsolatedStorageW8;
```

That will help. 
The **Setting** Class is in that namespace.
Maybe read about .Net Reflector or ReSharper. These can help when you are in same trouble.

The .Net reflector can help to watch the arhitecure of a dll.
The ReSharper can suggest to you the usings or references, and of course a lot of another tips.